# weblogic 12.1.3 config.sh DISPLAY error

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm configuring a fresh installation of WebLogic 12.1.3. Over ssh no graphics available.

When I try to create a domain with the command:

```
./config.sh -mode=console
```

I get the error below:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:11.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
```

I tried to remove $JVM_D64 from global config.sh and it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console mode was removed somewhere after 12.1.1.  The available [Modes of Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/OUIRF/overview.htm#OUIRF356) are now just graphical or silent.